# Will WooCommerce allow the site owner to buy the product for the user?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a new site I'll be working on that has two methods for users to buy tickets - use credits or use a credit card. I'm redoing the site in WordPress and WooCommerce.

The owner can, on his current site, charge the customer's credit card for the product via the backend. Does WooCommerce allow that?

**Basically, can the owner buy the product under the customer's account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kimberly, By default WooCommerce doesn't provide a feature to process payment from the backend. You should just tweak the process. Here is the article that may help you to achieve. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/processing-woocommerce-payments-customer/

Or else you need to add a custom module|plugins to process payment from the backend.
Thanks

Comment: This looks great. Appreciate it!